# I am troubling integrating react-Dropzone-Uploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

The image data which is requested by the API is multipart form data but i am just providing the image data to it.i want to convert the image data to FormData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`FormData`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

You'll need to use the [**`append`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method on it to add the image.

Here's some sample code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('nameOfTheKeyYouWantToSetThisDataTo', myFileInput.files[0], 'avatar.jpg');
```

You can then send the data to your API using the [**`fetch`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  }).then(function (response) {
     ...
  });
```